# My HTML Content disappear after saving in Opencart Module

Tags: php, html, css, opencart, e-commerce

I'm recently learning opencart Application. When I am adding some content to my Home page by using opencart module it disappear. But If I put some normal text, I am not facing any problem. But when I put some HTML Content with text It disappear. I don't know where is my mistake and how can i solve this?

Can anyone help me?

NO PROBLEM WHEN I WRITE NORMAL TEXT

[image]

PROBLEM WHEN I WRITE TEXT INSIDE MULTIPLE DIV OR TAGS

[image]

NOTE: I'm Using Opencart default childtheme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is your solution:
[image]

After putting your html content in the code editor you have to click again into the text mood. Then save it... 
Your problem will be solved.

Comment: you make my day

Comment: @YuAnShaolinMaculelêLai I'm glad to help

Comment: Thank you! I am so happy to know that someone else had this problem and it was solved. I love OpenCart, but even stupid stuff like this is met with "you should hire a developer" on the OpenCart forums.  Love the platform, hate the so-called "community support" that is provided. Thanks again!